# Generate power through a charger

Tags: power-electronics

I have 100 Nm going into a charging device such as a dynamo, alternator, etc. The rotation is 20 radians per second. The charger is 3-phase with a frequency of 50 Hz and 12 poles. What is the potential power output running over 1 hour in kWh?

Comment: What is the efficency of the "charging device such as dynamo alternator etc" at 20 radians per second? Power is speed times toqure, so 20x100=2000W power in, power out will be that times efficency. But I'm not sure what this has to do with electrical design.

Comment: the efficiency is a nominal 70%, excuse my ignorance of electronics but when you say 2000W does that mean over one hour it will be 2Kwh less efficiency

Comment: Yes 2000W is 2kW of power delivery. If you supply 2kW for 1 hour, it will be 2kWh. If we assume 70% efficency, 2kW in becomes 2*0.7=1.4kW. So 1.4kW of power, over 1 hour this would be 1.4kWh. Over 2 hours this would be 2.8kWh. And so on.

Answer (score 1):

> I have 100 Nm going into a charging device such as a dynamo, alternator, etc. The rotation is 20 radians per second.

You have a mechanical input of 100 * 20 = 2000 Watts

> The charger is 3-phase with a frequency of 50 Hz and 12 poles.

Irrelevant

> What is the potential power output running over 1 hour in kWh?

kWh is a measure of energy, not power.

The power output will be somewhere between the bounds of 0 and 2000 W, depending on the efficiency of the generator and anything that follows it, so maybe 1 kW, maybe 1.5 kW?

The energy output in kWh in one hour will be numerically equal to the power output.